# Does foreach apply boxing on IEnumerable<struct>?

Tags: c#, optimization, boxing

I believe the C# compiler will rewrite `foreach` into a `for` when it is used on ordinary arrays (such as `int[]`). However, for collections that store a `struct`, will boxing result from iterating its contents?

For example, does the code below rely on boxing (`IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int,byte>>`) to iterate the contents of `dict`?

```
void DoSomething(Dictionary<int,byte> dict) {
    foreach(KeyValuePair<int,byte> itr in dict)
        m_correlation += itr.Key; }
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling such code and the using `ildasm` or `ilspy` on the resulting assembly to look for `box` opcodes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the above code does no boxing.

If you'd used `IDictionary<int, byte>` as the argument (or `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, byte>>`), the **enumerator** itself would get boxed, since the dictionary class, like many collections, have a `struct` enumerator (to save an object allocation every time you call `foreach`).

In the code above, the compiler would call the dictionary's `GetEnumerator` method, rather than the (implicitly implemented) `IEnumerable<T>` method.

Answer (score 1):

No it won't.

Nothing from the above *can* be boxed. Your `Dictionary` is already a reference type.. and a `KeyValuePair` is a `struct`. The compiler generated call to `GetEnumerator()` will return a generic Enumerator `struct`.. but that is called on `dict`.. which is already a reference type.